# Inserting PDFs into an SQL table

Tags: sql-server

So I'm trying to read a bunch of PDFs from a folder into an SQL table, saving them in a varbinary(max) field. This is what I thought would work at first:

```
CREATE TABLE tempFileName(filnavn VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO tempFileName
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B "C:\temp\Test Folder\"';
--------
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(100) SET @path = 'C:\temp\Test Folder\'
DECLARE @pdf VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @navn varchar(50)
DECLARE @fullpath nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
    SELECT filnavn
    FROM tempFileName
OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @navn
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
        SET @fullpath = @path + @navn
        SELECT @pdf = BulkColumn
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @fullpath, SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;
        --print @sql

        INSERT INTO pdftest VALUES(@navn, @pdf)
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @navn
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

But this doesn't work as it won't allow me to use a variable in this line:

```
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @fullpath, SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;
```

So I'm pretty sure the trick is to make the whole "select @pdf.." line into a string and then execute it, but I'm not sure how to get the output into a table. I've tried something like this:

```
SET @fullpath = @path + @navn
SET @sql = 'DECLARE @pdf VARBINARY(MAX) SELECT @pdf = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @fullpath + ''' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;'
--print @sql

--SELECT @pdf, DATALENGTH(@pdf)
--INSERT INTO pdftest VALUES(@navn, @pdf)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@fil varbinary(max) out', @fil out
```

But the @fil variable is just empty after this. How do I best go about getting these files into a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just skip the variable assignment of the SELECT in your loop and use the OPENROWSET function inside your INSERT? The general idea:

```
INSERT INTO pdftest SELECT @navn, * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK, 'C:\thefile.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS document
```

And of course turn above into dynamic SQL. I'll probably get a few single-quotes wrong here, but again the general idea:

```
SET @sql = 
'INSERT INTO pdftest
SELECT '' + @navn + '', *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK, ''' + @fullpath + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS document
'
```